# Memoization only under certain conditions

Tags: memoization

I have a function that takes in sequences of values (as a list), and recursively removes the largest element from that sequence as part of its computation. Some of these sequences can be quite large, but I suspect that they often have common subsequences. So I want to memoize my function, but I don't want to memoize it for very large sequences, only smaller sequences which these larger sequences might have in common. I tried something like this,

```
f[sequence_?Length[#] < 16 &] := f[sequence] = f[sequence]
```

where `f` is already defined elsewhere. Probably I would need to memoize for larger sequences, but that's the idea of it. However, I hit the recursion limit when I call this function.

Comment: Is the second `f[sequence]` on the right-hand side actually some expression involving `sequence`? And as far as the left-hand side goes, I think you need to do `f[sequence_?(Length[#] < 16 &)]` because of operator precedence issues.

Comment: The second `f[sequence]` on the right hand side is defined like `f[sequence_] := ...`. Adding parenthesis doesn't change the error I get.

Comment: This feels like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - why not show an example of what it is you're trying to get to, and *why* - there's probably a succinct and efficient way to do it...

Comment: By the way, it is a good idea to wait for at least a day before accepting an answer. That way, you will likely attract more answers, and they might be more to your liking (that green check-mark can be a deterrent to new answers!). In addition, @ciao's point is well-taken: you might consider outlining your actual problem (although I like the particular question of sometimes-memoization, although now that I think about it, I suspect this might be a duplicate...)

Comment: @march, Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Also with regards to being a duplicate, I searched but couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: @ciao, My actual problem is one of mapping sequences that represent unique $k$-length partitions of a set to integers in the range $\left[0,{n \brace k}\right)$, where $n$ is the length of the original set and $k$ is the length of all the partitions I'm interested in. Currently I'm using the method described [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/61140/compact-reversible-mapping-from-set-partitions-of-length-k-to-integers).

Comment: @JordyDickinson - it appears you are after the ranking/unranking of k-block set partitions, There is already built-in functionality for that... hence the XY comment...

Comment: @ciao, I may be wrong, but I don't believe that's what I'm looking for. I'm looking to map _set_ partitions to integers, not integer partitions. Also these integers must be unique.

Comment: @JordyDickinson- Umm, that's exactly what I described, e.g., the rank of `{{a}, {b}, {c, d, e}}` in the 3-block partition of `{a,b,c,d,e}` is 0, and that of `{{a, d}, {b, e}, {c}}` is 24. Is that not what you're doing?

Comment: @ciao, Sorry, you're right. That's exactly what I'm doing. I'm misunderstanding the meaning of "rank". However, the function I believe you're describing is in the Combinatorica package, which I don't have.

Comment: @ciao, In fact, I've discovered through reading about that function that there is a name for another part of what I'm doing of which I was unaware, so now I have some new reading material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function twice, once without the memoization, and once with the memoization and your condition.

Consider this simple example:

```
Clear@f
f[{}] = {};
f[a_List] := Rest@a
f[a_List /; Length@a <= 3] := f[a] = Rest@a
```

If we run

```
FixedPointList[f, Range[5]]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5}, {5}, {}, {}} *)
```

then

[image]

Notice that it has saved only those lists of length less than 4.

---

Alternatively, if it is annoying to define the function twice, do this instead. It works the same.

```
Clear@f
f[{}] = {};
f[a_List] := If[Length@a > 3, #, f[a] = #]&@Rest@a
```

Comment: This does indeed fix my problem. I just wish there was an elegant way to do it, without all the code repetition.

Comment: @JordyDickinson. In my opinion, this sort of construction *is* elegant, and is very *Mathematica*-idiomatic. But I have posted an alternative solution.